# Android ViewPager fakeDragBy

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm attempting to make my ViewPager bounce a few times on first load to indicate to the user that what they are looking at is a horizontally scrollable view. I've tried to use fakeDragBy but my app will crash when I attempt to do this. What is the recommended way to use fakeDragBy properly to achieve what I am seeking?

Here is the code I am running inside my Activity:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    mViewPager.beginFakeDrag();
    mViewPager.fakeDragBy(25);
    mViewPager.endFakeDrag();
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
09-24 12:21:49.702  28243-28243/com.company E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company, PID: 28243
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company/com.company.onboarding.OnboardingActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.fakeDragBy(ViewPager.java:2431)
            at com.company.onboarding.OnboardingActivity.onStart(OnboardingActivity.java:100)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Post a stack trace from logcat, and preferably some code to show how you are using it.

Comment: @Karakuri I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you pay close attention to the error log:

`Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.fakeDragBy(ViewPager.java:2431)`

Your view pager has *zero* items at the time of the fakeDragBy. That means that the Adapter is not giving your view pager any data, so the ViewPager is not ready to do anything.

We'd need to see how/when you are initializing your ViewPager. Without those bits of information, it's impossible to tell why you're getting an Out of Bounds exception.

Please add more code.

The issue could be else where, it's hard to tell, since you seem to be able to `setCurrentItem(0)` without problems.

As a side note, the Google's recommendation of *wiggling* the view pager upon startup to help discovery, mentions that this should only be done *once*. Since you're adding code to `onStart()` I guess you intend to do it every time you start the Activity, careful with that ;)